# How to have a conditional attribute in Svelte 3?

Tags: html, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

Is there a simpler way to write the following checkbox component:

```
<script>
  export let disabled = false;
</script>

{#if disabled}
  <label class="checkbox" disabled>
    <input type="checkbox" {disabled} />
    <slot></slot>
  </label>
{:else}
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" {disabled} />
    <slot></slot>
  </label>
{/if}
```

Having `<label disabled="false">` is not acceptable because Bulma have a CSS class `.checkbox[disabled]`.

Comment: found [this article](https://stacktuts.com/how-to-have-a-conditional-attribute-in-svelte-3) which can be helpful

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`disabled || null` (or `disabled || undefined`) will do the trick:

```html
<label class="checkbox" disabled={disabled || null}>
  <input type="checkbox" {disabled} />
  <slot></slot>
</label>
```

From the [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-attributes-and-props):

> ... [A]ttributes are included unless their value is [nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish)
> (`null` or `undefined`).
>
> ```html
> <input required={false} placeholder="This input field is not required">
> <div title={null}>This div has no title attribute</div>
> ```

Comment: The `autofocus` in Svelte only works when it has no value - not even an empty string or true / false can be.
How to solve it? What it comes from?

Comment: `attributes are included unless their value is nullish (null or undefined).` is a really useful way to toggle attributes